# How to do server side render using next.js?

Tags: server-side-rendering, next.js

When I create a simple app, I found that next.js will automatically do the server side render.

But when I tried to fetch the data from backend, I found that server side won't get the data.

How to fetch the data from server side? So that I can do the server side render?

**components/test.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Test extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            'test':''
        }
    }

    setTest(){

        axios.get(serverName+'/api/articles/GET/test').then(response=>{

            let test;
            test = response.data.test;
            this.setState({test});

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.test}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Test;
```

backend is just like following:

```
function getTest(Request $request){
    return response()->json(['test'=>'this is a test']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Next.js uses `getInitialProps` that is executed on the server on initial load only.

From [docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle)

> For the initial page load, `getInitialProps` will execute on the server
>   only. `getInitialProps` will only be executed on the client when
>   navigating to a different route via the `Link` component or using the
>   routing APIs.

All other lifecycle methods/actions on React components (componentDidMount, onClick, onChange etc) are executed on the client side.

Example code

```
class Test extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps() {
    const response = await axios.get(serverName + '/api/articles/GET/test');

    return { test: response.data.test }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.test}</div>;
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: Ok, I'm checking the document right now. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: i've updated the answer with the code. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Like below. I would recomend to use `getInitialProps`. This is recommended approach by next.js to get data at server.

```js
import React from 'react'

export default class extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
  
  axios.get(serverName+'/api/articles/GET/test').then(response=>{
            let test;
            test = response.data.test;
            return { test }
        }).catch(function (error) {
             return { response }
        });  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello World {this.props.test.name}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to run the code but failed. I add console.log('test:   ',test); inside axios function and found that response can be receive at getInitialProps. 
But {this.props.test} can't get anything. Am I do something wrong?